# Arduino compiling error in platformio with bool readSerial(Serial& stream) -> stream not declared

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, serial-port, platformio

I tried to compile a code in platformio (Atom) and got a compiler error.
No compiling errors for this code in the Arduino IDE.
How do I get this code work with the PlatformIO compiler?

I don't really understand how "bool readSerial(Serial& stream)" gets the Serial stream because I copied a part of the code here:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serielle-schnittstelle-langsam/414027/2

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Full code posted now and all errors.

```
src\main.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
src\main.cpp:25:4: error: 'readSerial' was not declared in this scope
 if(readSerial(Serial) == true)
src\main.cpp:25:4: note: suggested alternative: 'Serial'
 if(readSerial(Serial) == true)
src\main.cpp: At global scope:
src\main.cpp:48:25: error: 'stream' was not declared in this scope
 bool readSerial(Serial& stream)
src\main.cpp:48:25: note: suggested alternative: 'Stream'
 bool readSerial(Serial& stream)
```

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

int soundSensor = 3;                                              //Deklaration der Variable Soundsensor an Pin3
int relay = 4;                                                    //Deklaration der Variable Relais an Pin4
boolean lightState = false;                                       //Deklaration der Variable Lichtstatus

// Serial stuff
const int SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
byte serialBuffer[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

String command;

void setup() {
  pinMode(soundSensor, INPUT);                                    //Pin3 wird als Eingang deklariert
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);                                         //Pin4 wird als Ausgang deklariert
  Serial.begin(115200);                                           //Test für seriellen Monitor
  //MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);


}

void loop()
{

if(readSerial(Serial) == true)
{
  //Serial.println(serialBuffer[0]);

  if(serialBuffer[0] == 97)
  {
    if (!lightState)
    {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    lightState = true;
    }

    else if (lightState)
    {
      digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
      lightState = false;
    }
  }

}
}                                                                 //ENDE


bool readSerial(Serial& stream)
  {
  static byte streamindex = 0;

  while(stream.available())
  {
    byte c = stream.read();
    serialBuffer[streamindex] = c;
    streamindex ++;

    if(streamindex > SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE -1)
    {
      streamindex = 0;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: Is that the only error? Could there be a mistake in the `//Do sth` that confuses the compiler enough that it throws out a false positive later in the code? Don't do Sith, by the way. They have many abilities some consider to be... unnatural.

Comment: Your log says the error is on line 51, but the code you posted has 43 lines in it. So clearly the code that produces the error is not the code you posted.

Comment: My paranoid fear: There is a `bool readSerial(Stream &stream)` instead of a proper function call somewhere in the lands of sth.

Comment: @Frank Yes...you're right it wasn't the full code. I cut out some thinks which (AFAIK) don't belong to my problem. But you are right with your comment. The magic of problems are given by the things which don't seem to be a problem.
I posted the full code now.

Comment: @user4581301 That's the part I didn't understand in the code.I hate it to copy code but I had no other choice because this kind of serial stuff is new to me.
How could a proper function call work in my case?

Comment: The code works in the Arduino IDE. Thats the magic thing.

Comment: The `readSerial` function needs to be moved above `loop` or forward declared (I prefer the move because it removes the possibility of a mismatch between the declaration and implementation) to eliminate `'readSerial' was not declared in this scope`.  `Serial` is used like a globally defined variable, not a type in `setup`. I don't know Arduinio worth crap, but the examples I'm seeing floating around suggest the same. Looks like you just use `Serial` as is

Comment: I also don't really like the Arduino "crap" but it gives a much motivation to learn without losing the motivation.

Comment: I may have been misinterpreted slightly there. I'm not calling Arduino crap. I'm calling my level of knowledge about Arduino crap.

Comment: I'm sorry. My english is not the yellow from the egg (german phrase) :)

Comment: No, my fault for using a colloquialism on an international web page.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code now. The compiler couldn't know what the function does, because the function was declared before the main loop. I also removed the "Stream& stream" argument. I don't know what the author of the code meant. But it works pretty fine now with this code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int soundSensor = 3;                                              //Deklaration der Variable Soundsensor an Pin3
int relay = 4;                                                    //Deklaration der Variable Relais an Pin4
boolean lightState = false;                                       //Deklaration der Variable Lichtstatus

// Serial stuff
const int SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
byte serialBuffer[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

String command;

void setup() {
  pinMode(soundSensor, INPUT);                                    //Pin3 wird als Eingang deklariert
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);                                         //Pin4 wird als Ausgang deklariert
  Serial.begin(115200);                                           //Test für seriellen Monitor
  //MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);


}

bool readSerial()
  {
  static byte streamindex;
  static byte c;

  while(Serial.available())
  {
    c = Serial.read();
    serialBuffer[streamindex] = c;
    streamindex ++;

    if(streamindex > SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE -1)
    {
      streamindex = 0;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  }

void loop()
{

if(readSerial() == true)
{
  //Serial.println(serialBuffer[0]);

  if(serialBuffer[0] == 97)
  {
    if (!lightState)
    {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    lightState = true;
    }

    else if (lightState)
    {
      digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
      lightState = false;
    }
  }

}
}
```